# Merging key-value sets as specified by a command

Tags: java, performance

```
private void merge(ArrayList<String> operations, ArrayList<LinkedHashSet<String>> setOfStrings) {
        String toMerge = operations.get(1);
        String fromMerge = operations.get(2);
        boolean enteredFirstToMerge = false;
        boolean enteredFirstForMerge = false;
        // references that points one on toMerge and the other on fromMerge
        LinkedHashSet<String> toMergeAndAfterDelete = null;
        LinkedHashSet<String> addOnFromMerge = null;
        for (LinkedHashSet<String> subSet : setOfStrings) {
        if (subSet.contains(toMerge) && subSet.contains(fromMerge))
            break;
        else {
            if (subSet.contains(toMerge) && !enteredFirstToMerge) {
            toMergeAndAfterDelete = subSet;
            enteredFirstToMerge = true;
            }
            if (subSet.contains(fromMerge) && !enteredFirstForMerge) {
            addOnFromMerge = subSet;
            enteredFirstForMerge = true;
            }
            if ((enteredFirstForMerge && enteredFirstToMerge)) {
            break;
            }
          }
        }
        /***********************************************/
        //outside Loop i call the remove on the arraylist
        //that are very expensive    
        /*************************************************/   
        if (enteredFirstForMerge && enteredFirstToMerge) {
        // first i delete from the array the linkedHashSet toMerge and
        // fromMerge and after i add a 
        // new linkedHashSet with the subSets merged
        setOfStrings.remove(toMergeAndAfterDelete);  
        setOfStrings.remove(addToMergeOnFromMerge); 
        addOnFromMerge.addAll(toMergeAndAfterDelete);
        setOfStrings.add(addOnFromMerge);
        }
}
```

This function takes as parameter an `arrayList` of operations, and an `ArrayList<LinkedHashSet<String>>`:

For the `arrayList` of `operations`, I always get a specific position, so I don't iterate.    It is always \$O(1)\$.

For example, if I have as operation `move foo bar`, I have to do these steps:

- First of all, I have to find where are located `foo` and `bar`:

  - Inside `setOfStrings`, I can have this situation:

    ```
        position x : {bar tree hotel}
        ...
        position y : {foo lemon coffee}
    ```

When I find them, I have to  concat the `foo string into bar string`  in this way:

```
            position x : {bar tree hotel foo lemon coffee}
            ...
            position y : {}
```

How can I improve the efficiency of this function?

Comment: The number one problem with your code is the formatting. Fix that and you're half done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Abstract as much as possible over type: `List` instead of `ArrayList`.
- Use OO where appropriate: `List<String> operations` should clearly be some
  `class MoveOperation(String to, String from)`.
- It's not clear why you are using `LinkedHashSet` instead of `List`.
- The algorithm is ill-defined: what happens if there are numerous
  foo's or bar's.

I implemented something below, but it is in functional style, so it might be hard to read.  There are three implicit loops: two for the `filter`s and one for the `map`.  You might also notice that I never modify a collection, but always create a new one.  Again, this is the functional style.  In your algorithm, you can actually shoot yourself in the foot if you modify some collections at the wrong moment.

```
private List<List<String>> merge2(List<String> operations, List<List<String>> listOfSentences) {
    Stream<List<String>> sentencesWithTo = listOfSentences.stream()
                                           .filter(sentence -> sentence.contains(toMerge));
    Stream<List<String>> sentencesWithFrom = listOfSentences.stream()
                                             .filter(sentence -> sentence.contains(fromMerge));

    long nTo = sentencesWithTo.count();
    long nFrom = sentencesWithFrom.count();

    if (nTo == 0  || nFrom == 0) {
        return listOfSentences;
    } else if (nTo > 1 || nFrom > 1) {
        // what to do here??
    } else {
        List<String> sentenceTo = sentencesWithTo.collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0); // should only be one element ?
        List<String> sentenceFrom = sentencesWithFrom.collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0); // should only be one element ?
        Stream<List<String>> updatedSentences = listOfSentences.stream().map(sentence -> {
            if (sentence.equals(sentenceTo))
                return Stream.concat(sentenceTo.stream(), sentenceFrom.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            else if (sentence.equals(sentenceFrom))
                return new ArrayList<>();
            else 
                return sentence;
        });
        return updatedSentences.collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to point out, this code snippet does not demonstrate what you have asked:

```
    // first i delete from the array the linkedHashSet toMerge and
    // fromMerge and after i add a 
    // new linkedHashSet with the subSets merged
    setOfStrings.remove(toMergeAndAfterDelete);  
    setOfStrings.remove(addToMergeOnFromMerge); 
    addOnFromMerge.addAll(toMergeAndAfterDelete);
    setOfStrings.add(addOnFromMerge);
```

> - First of all, I have to find where are located `foo` and `bar`:
>
>   - Inside `setOfStrings`, I can have this situation:
>
>     ```
>        position x : {bar tree hotel}
>         ...
>         position y : {foo lemon coffee}
>     ```
>
> When I find them, I have to  concat the `foo string into bar string`  in this way:
>
> ```
>            position x : {bar tree hotel foo lemon coffee}
>             ...
>             position y : {}
> ```

Your code is doing more like:

```
position z : {bar tree hotel foo lemon coffee}
```

Other minor points to highlight too:

- `ArrayList<LinkedHashSet<String>> setOfStrings` isn't exactly a set of `String`s, more like a list of set of `String`s... in other words, perhaps you can think of a better variable name.
- Same for the other names e.g. `toMerge` and `fromMerge`, I don't think they are easily understandable when reading the code.
- Program to interfaces, not the implementations. I.e. instead of `merge(ArrayList<String> operations, ArrayList<LinkedHashSet<String>> setOfStrings)` the method signature can be `merge(List<String> operations, List<Set<String>> setOfStrings)`.